# How to debug Crash Logs

Tags: objective-c

Any one help me to debug Crash Logs.Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Do you have actual crash logs that you want help debugging, or are you asking generally how to go about debugging them?

Comment: generally how to go about debugging them?

Answer (score 1):

If you're a registered developer, there's a great talk from WWDC 2010 that goes through this. It's "Session 317 - Understanding Crash Reports." It's on iTunes U.